# subprocess of sudo, accessing /dev/sda : strange error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, subprocess, sudo

I'm trying to read smart (by nagios user) with this script:
https://gist.github.com/mastbaum/10663894#file-smart_watch-py

I did enable nagios to execute that file (/etc/sudoers):

```
nagios  ALL= NOPASSWD: /git/check_smart/smart_watch.py
#(later on for testing)
nagios  ALL= NOPASSWD: ALL
```

I'm pretty sure I get root permission inside the subprocess, it seems that the access to the device is not granted:

```
nagios@x:/dir$ sudo /git/check_smart/smart_watch.py --device /dev/sda
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/git/check_smart/smart_watch.py", line 48, in <module>
    main(args.logfile, args.device)
  File "/git/check_smart/smart_watch.py", line 18, in main
    code = check_smart(device)
  File "/git/check_smart/smart_watch.py", line 10, in check_smart
    return subprocess.call(args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 493, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1259, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

$ ls -lahtr /dev/sda
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 0 cze 13 14:55 /dev/sda
```

The command run perfect executed as root.

**Any ideas why there is "No such file" error?** 
I did expect permission deny, but not the /no file/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it

command was not finding smartclt, changed to:
/usr/sbin/smartctl

Comment: The little check mark next to the upvote down vote buttons